# ImportError: cannot import name 'tasks_v2' from 'google.cloud'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I'm trying to use the Google Cloud Tasks code sample provided in the GCP documentation here:
https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks (see code below). However, it's unclear from the documentation which package I need for this to work. Any ideas?

However, I'm getting the following error.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'tasks_v2' from 'google.cloud'
```

Code sample:

```py
from google.cloud import tasks_v2
from google.protobuf import timestamp_pb2

# Create a client.
client = tasks_v2.CloudTasksClient()

# TODO(developer): Uncomment these lines and replace with your values.
# project = 'my-project-id'
# queue = 'my-appengine-queue'
# location = 'us-central1'
# payload = 'hello'

# Construct the fully qualified queue name.
parent = client.queue_path(project, location, queue)

# Construct the request body.
task = {
        'app_engine_http_request': {  # Specify the type of request.
            'http_method': 'POST',
            'relative_uri': '/example_task_handler'
        }
}
if payload is not None:
    # The API expects a payload of type bytes.
    converted_payload = payload.encode()

    # Add the payload to the request.
    task['app_engine_http_request']['body'] = converted_payload

if in_seconds is not None:
    # Convert "seconds from now" into an rfc3339 datetime string.
    d = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=in_seconds)

    # Create Timestamp protobuf.
    timestamp = timestamp_pb2.Timestamp()
    timestamp.FromDatetime(d)

    # Add the timestamp to the tasks.
    task['schedule_time'] = timestamp

# Use the client to build and send the task.
response = client.create_task(parent, task)

print('Created task {}'.format(response.name))
return response
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
pip3 install -U google-cloud-tasks
```

If you get any problems importing packages for other GCP services, this is a great resource:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python. The links point straight to the relevant package names on [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/).

Answer (score 5):

When following any guide on the GCP docs, go the github repo and search for the **requirements.txt** file, here will be alll the dependencies used as well  as the versions.

For the [creating http task](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks) the requirements file would be [this one](https://github.com/googleapis/python-tasks/blob/master/samples/snippets/requirements.txt).

It has

```
google-cloud-tasks==2.0.0
```

This is the exact dependency and version you are looking for