# ImportError: cannot import name 'tasks_v2' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location) in Python fastapi

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I'm trying to incorporate `google-cloud-tasks` Python client within my fastapi app. But it's giving me an import error like this:

```
from google.cloud import tasks_v2
ImportError: cannot import name 'tasks_v2' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)
```

packages in my project, `pip freeze`:

```
aiohttp==3.8.1
aiosignal==1.2.0
async-timeout==4.0.2
attrs==21.4.0
boto3==1.20.51
botocore==1.23.51
CacheControl==0.12.10
cachetools==4.2.4
certifi==2021.10.8
charset-normalizer==2.0.11
click==7.1.2
confuse==1.4.0
firebase-admin==5.0.1
Flask==1.1.4
frozenlist==1.3.0
google-api-core==1.31.5
google-api-python-client==2.36.0
google-auth==1.35.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
google-cloud==0.34.0
google-cloud-core==2.2.2
google-cloud-firestore==2.3.4
google-cloud-storage==2.1.0
google-cloud-tasks==2.7.2
google-crc32c==1.3.0
google-resumable-media==2.2.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.54.0
greenlet==1.1.2
grpc-google-iam-v1==0.12.3
grpcio==1.43.0
grpcio-status==1.43.0
httplib2==0.20.4
idna==3.3
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
jmespath==0.10.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
msgpack==1.0.3
multidict==6.0.2
numpy==1.22.2
packaging==21.3
pandas==1.3.2
proto-plus==1.20.0
protobuf==3.19.4
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycryptodome==3.14.1
pyee==7.0.4
PyMySQL==1.0.2
pyparsing==3.0.7
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-dotenv==0.19.1
pytz==2021.3
PyYAML==6.0
requests==2.27.1
rsa==4.8
s3transfer==0.5.1
schedule==1.1.0
six==1.16.0
slackclient==2.9.3
slackeventsapi==2.2.1
SQLAlchemy==1.4.22
uritemplate==4.1.1
urllib3==1.26.8
Werkzeug==1.0.1
yarl==1.7.2
```

Python version I'm using for this virtualenv is `Python 3.8.9`

OS: `macOS Monterey 12.1`

Tried this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65079497/importerror-cannot-import-name-tasks-v2-from-google-cloud), but it didn't work. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some more research online I realized that installation of some packages is missed due to some existing packages. [This](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/6259) issue helped me realize I need to reorder the position of `google-cloud-tasks` in my requirements.txt. So what I did was pretty simple, created a new virtualenv installed `google-cloud-tasks` as my first package and then installed everything else and finally the problem is solved.

Long story short the issue is the order in which packages are installed and that's why some packages are getting missed.